# jquery ajax always error even when update happens

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

When i call the function below:

```
function savePlace(id) {
var myName     = $('#placeName').val();
var myAtmosphere     = $('#placeAtmosphere').val()
var myType     = $('#placeFoodType').val()
var myPrice     = $('#placePrice').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "savePlace.php",
    data: {"placeID" : id, "placeName": myName, "placeAtmosphere" : myAtmosphere, "placeType": myType, "placePrice" : myPrice},  
    dataType:"html",
    success: function(data){
        alert("YES");
    },
    // error function is always being called - even if database gets updated correctly
    error: function (data) {
        alert("no");
    }
});
return false;
}
```

it will run - in that it will execute the php in savePlace.php (which runs a mysql update command).  savePlace.php returns nothing currently, but it could return html or text if it's needed.
In any case, the error handler is always executed.  i have checked in the chrome js inspector, and it reports:

```
statusText:"error"
responseText:""
status:0
```

Here is the mysql code, if that helps

```
<?php
require_once 'config/Common.php';
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
$placeID = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['placeID']));
$placeID = (int)$placeID;
$placeName = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['placeName']));
$placeAtmosphere = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['placeAtmosphere']));
$placeType = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['placeType']));
$placePrice = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['placePrice']));
$stmt = $EAE_CON->prepare("UPDATE EAE_PLACES SET NAME=?,ATMOSPHERE=?,FOOD_TYPE=?,PRICE=? WHERE idEAE_PLACES=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi',$placeName, $placeAtmosphere, $placeType, $placePrice, $placeID);
$stmt->execute();
echo "Stuff";
?>
```

Note: I am running on localhost (my local machine, XAMPP)

Comment: Is your PHP on the same domain as the calling script?

Comment: Use firebug etc. to  see what you actually get from the server. Most likely something goes wrong and you do not get a 200 response code.

Comment: Change your error callback to error: function(data, status, err){ console.log(data); console.log(status); console.log(err); }, to see if you can get more information.  Also, unless you're expecting HTML from the server, don't state the dataType.

Comment: in the php code?  i made the edit above and there was no change.

Comment: And if your savePlace.php file contains nothing but a simple text like 'hello'?

Comment: in your php, did you put *echo "<p>Stuff</p>";* on the last line?  your ajax request is looking for html.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I had to change the markup of a button that activated this function.  For some reason that affected this.

I changed it from a  to a .  I'm not sure why that made a difference, but it appears to have fixed the problem.